# Inicio de sesion con java

Tags: java, php

Estoy realizando una pagina web en jsp con netbeans y necesito validar que el usuario haya iniciado sesión para mostrar algunas paginas que deberían estar restringidas  he hecho esto antes pero con php de la siguiente forma

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['missael']))
    header('Location: index.php');
```

ahora necesito implementarlo con java, alguna idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java EE, la sesión se maneja a través de la interfaz [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). Puedes obtener la sesión mediante el método [`HttpServletRequest#getSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession--):

```
HttpServletRequest request = ...; //quizás sea parámetro de tu método
//obtienes la sesión
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
//puedes colocar datos en la sesión
session.setAttribute("usuario", "algo");
//puedes obtener dicho dato luego
//como devuelve un Object, debes hacer el casteo apropiado
String algo = (String)session.getAttribute("usuario");
//puedes remover datos de la sesión
session.removeAttribute("remueveme");
//para cerrar la sesión (en el logout), utilizas el método invalidate
session.invalidate();
```